# How can integrate PHP debugbar with MySQLI?

Tags: php, mysqli, phpdebugbar

The documentation on how to do this with PDO is [pretty straightforward](http://phpdebugbar.com/docs/base-collectors.html#pdo). However, not much can be found on how can I setup Php debugbar collector to log queries for a MYSQLI database connection ? Is this possible, and if so, then how can I achieve it ?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't switch to PDO?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a standard collector for mysqli, but you should be able to create a one of your own.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
Yes, code base is too big. It's too much to refactor atm.

Comment: @Dharman
Any advice or documentation on how to do that ?